# sorting algorithm its worst case O(n)

Tags: sorting

is it possible to sort an array of strings by word length and the sorting algorithm complexity will be O(n) as worst case?

Comment: Are you defining `n` in the conventional sense of the number of elements in the array, or in the strict formal sense of the number of bits required to represent the input?

Comment: so, I will ask the user to enter n, which will represent the number of words the user wants to add to the string array, and then the user will enter the nth words. after that I need to find a sorting algorithm that will sort the array by its word length and the challenge here is that, the wort case should be O(n) of my algorithm.

Comment: Then it is impossible.

Comment: @kaya3 - radix sort has time complexity O(n) if maximum word length is a constant.

Comment: @rcgldr Yes, and so does counting sort; but the question doesn't say the word length is bounded. On the contrary, if the words come directly from user input then they are not bounded. But radix sort or counting sort would be linear in the number of bits of input, which is why I asked.

Comment: @kaya3 - I posted an answer, The issue is if the maximum word length is a constant, in which case it's not included in time complexity. Similarly, a base 256 -> 8 pass radix sort for 64 bit integers would be considered to have time complexity O(n), regardless of the actual range of values in an array or vector of 64 bit integers. If that 8 pass radix sort was optimized to use fewer passes for a smaller range, say 4 passes if range < 2^32, then time complexity would be O(k n), where k is the number of passes = ceiling(log256(range)), no longer a constant.

Comment: If your problem is sorting an array of integers within a constant range, then again, counting sort is also linear time. But your observation isn't useful in practice because comparison-based sorting algorithms tend to do better because of memory locality among other things, and your observation isn't *that* useful in theory because we tend not to assume the array elements are bounded by a constant.

Answer (score 0):

If the maximum word length is *k*, then radix sort has time complexity O(*k* *n*). If *k* is a constant, then the time complexity is O(*n*), since time complexity does not include constants.

For an array of words of variable length, the array can be copied into a matrix where each row is a word of fixed length, padded with trailing zeroes as needed, with a second matrix used for temp storage. The result would be a sorted matrix that could be copied back to the original array (removing the trailing zeroes).

An alternative is an array of pointers to each word plus a pointer to the end of the last word. A temp array of pointers is also allocated, and the radix sort would sort the array of pointers, after which the sorted pointers would be used to create a sorted array of words and then copied back to the original array.